# Weblinks / Deeplinks to outlook in MS graph API not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I retrieve webLinks for mail messages using the https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/user/123/messages API. However, navigating to the webLink from returned from these messages does not work. It shows a loop on the page but the inbox or mail never opens

e.g:

"webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AAMkADk2MWI2NzQxLTYxMDgtNDsDfNhMS04ZDI3LWFjODM3ODAzYmFiYgBGAAAAAADETrax6m29TYnJ%2FzggnZWSBwB%2FS6EiGRtsS4DHOXO8xhxWAAAAAAEMAAB%2FS6EiGRtsS4DHOXO8xhxWAAAcI32XAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem"

It seems like an issue that was resolved here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1095

That GitHub repo seems to be a js repo so I am reopening it.

Comment: Interesting. I tried repro the issue and it worked for me. Make sure you use the latest browser build and SDK to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Could you please tell us which platform are you using?

Comment: We're seeing the same issue when using immutableIds. The weblink never works. We specifically need the deeplink for dealing with microsoft.graph.itemAttachment types.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I am using MS Graph API v1 to get the links and then open links via chrome

Comment: I randomly have this issue today as well for my app. Not sure why the web link takes you to a page envelope just reopening over and over.